# Cypress - getting values of element

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, cypress

I have the below two different HTML elements:

```
<h1 class="heading-1 page-header-heading">Collectie</h1>

<span class="results">4655</span>
```

I am able to get them using:

```
cy.get('.heading-1').should('have.class', 'heading-1 page-header-heading')
cy.get('.results').should('have.class', 'results')
```

But I need to extract the values in between, that is `Collectie` and `4655`

```
I tried :

cy.get('.heading-1').should('have.value', 'Collectie')
cy.get('.results').should('have.value', '4655')
```

But getting the below errors:

```
 expected '<h1.heading-1.page-header-heading>' to have value 'Collectie', but the value was ''
 expected '<span.results>' to have value '4655', but the value was ''
```

How should I get those 2 values in Cypress and validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `have.text` as you are asserting inner text.

```js
cy.get('.heading-1').should('have.text', 'Collectie')
cy.get('.results').should('have.text', '4655')
```

For case 1, in case you want to use both the class names you can do this:

```js
cy.get('.heading-1.page-header-heading').should('have.text', 'Collectie')
```

In case you want to check greater or less than, you can do like this:

```js
cy.get('.results')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => +text)
  .should('be.gt', 4000) // greater than
cy.get('.results')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => +text)
  .should('be.gte', 4000) // greater than equal to
cy.get('.results')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => +text)
  .should('be.lt', 9000) // less than
cy.get('.results')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => +text)
  .should('be.lte', 9000) // less than equal to
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the "Collectie". But the results number could change. So, I don't want to validate with a hard-coded value, instead check with a "should be greater than". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Besides using have.text, other thing you can do is using text() method within a promise combined with expect assertions. This way allows you to go further in your validation. Check bellow.

```
  cy.get('.heading-1').then(el => {
        let text = el.text()
        cy.log(`the expected text is: ${text}`)
        expect(text).equal('Collectie')
    })
```